# Removing items from the localStorage

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox, local-storage

I'm trying to remove the individual items from the localStorage. I'm using localStorage for storing selected list items in the listview. I attached the checkboxes for removing the selected items from the localstorage. But when I'm removing the selected checkboxes its not deleting properly like when I selected one checkbox its deleting two or three items are deleting from the localStorage.

Html code:

```
<!-- Favourites page -->
<div data-role="page" id="fav">
     <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
    </div>
    <div data-role="content" class="ulDiv">
    <ul data-role="listview" data-split-icon="minus" data-split-theme="d" data-filter="true"data-icon="false" data-filter-placeholder="Search" id="favoritesList">
            </ul>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" class="my-footer">
    </div>
</div>
```

My Js code:

```
 $(document).ready( function() {
    $("#section_list").on('click', 'a', function() {
                var item = $(this).find('h2').text();
                var desc = $(this).find('p').text();
                var html = '<p></br><p class="description">' + desc + '</p>';
                $('.addToFavoritesDiv').click(function() {
                    var url = $(location).attr('href');
                    if (!supportLocalStorage())
                    {
                        item = 'No support';
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        try
                            {
                                localStorage.setItem('autosave' + url, item + html);

                            }
                        catch (e)
                            {
                                if (e == QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR)
                                {
                                    alert('Quota Exceeded');
                                }
                            }   
                    }
                });
    });

    $('#fav').click(function() {
        fromStorage();
        $("#favoritesList").listview('refresh');
    }); 

    $(document).on('click', '#edit', function() {
        fromGetStorage();
    });
});

function supportLocalStorage()
{       
    return typeof(Storage) !== 'undefined';
}

function fromStorage()
{
    $("#favoritesList").empty();
    $("#favoritesList").listview('refresh');
    for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
        var url = localStorage.key(i);
            var item = localStorage.getItem(url);
            $("#favoritesList").append('<li id="add"><a href="' + url + '" style="text-decoration:none;color:black">' + item  + '</a></li>').attr('url', url);
    }
    $("#favoritesList").listview('refresh');
}

function fromGetStorage() 
    {   
     $("#favoritesList").empty();  
     $("#favoritesList").append('<input type="checkbox" name="all" id="select" />Select all</br>');
     $("#fav .ui-listview-filter").remove();
        for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
        var url = localStorage.key(i);
         var item = localStorage.getItem(url);
          $("#favoritesList").append('<li id="add"><div><input type="checkbox" name="check" id="check">&nbsp;<a href="' + url + '" style="text-decoration:none;color:black">' + item + '</a></div></li>').attr('url', url);
        $("#favoritesList").listview('refresh');
 }

$("#select").click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
});
    $('#select').change(function() {
    if($("#select").is(':checked')) {
        $("#add #check").prop("checked", true);
        $('#empty').on('click', function() {
            localStorage.clear();
        $("#favoritesList").listview('refresh');
        });
    }
    else {
        $("#add #check").prop("checked", false);
    }
 });


$("#add #check").click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
});

    $("#add #check").change(function() {
        var chkLength = $('input[name="check"]:checkbox').length;
        var chkdLength = $('input[name="check"]:checkbox:checked').length;
        if (chkLength == chkdLength)
        {
            $('#select').prop('checked', true);
        }
        else 
        {
            $('#select').prop('checked', false);
        }

});

$("#delete").on('click', function() {
                var checked = $('#add #check:checkbox:checked');
                    var url = localStorage.key(checked);
                    localStorage.removeItem(url);
                    $("#favoritesList").listview('refresh');
        });
}
```

Comment: you are deleting all data in local storage I think that's why ...

Comment: @imsiso localStorage.clear(); is for deleting all items its working fine but the problem is with localStorage.removeItem();

Comment: where is you HTML? and where is the code you are setting the local storage with that?

Comment: @imsiso i updated my complete code regarding the localstorage and Html as well.

Comment: Did you try using "delete window.localStorage[YourKey]"  ? this worked for me

Answer (score 15):

try removing items like this, removing local storage items by their key values

```
//syntax is localStorage.removeItem('keyName');
//so if your key name is checked                  
localStorage.removeItem('checked');
```

See this  [Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage) for reading about local storage.

Comment: At first I thought this would be the problem but It does not seem to be the actual way of removing keys.

Comment: It's working fine for me in both chrome and safari.  See this plunker and hit the more button, then choose delete database while looking at dev tools you should see the "settings" database delete.  [PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/3H1kgFKWsr341zsWLZvp)

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is in this part:

```
$("#delete").on('click', function() {
            var checked = $('#add #check:checkbox:checked');
            var url = localStorage.key(checked);
            localStorage.removeItem(url);
            $("#favoritesList").listview('refresh');
});
```

you are not using correct key for deleting and its because you are using :

```
var url = localStorage.key(checked);
```

and `checked==[Object]==1` so you are pointing to `localStorage.key(1)`

---

for solving this problem you can both use `key=localStorage.key(some);localStorage.removeItem(key);` and `localStorage.removeItem(some);` but the important part is that you should match 'an index(first way)' or a 'key value(the second way)' for each checkbox and I can help you if I have the complete code (I think still there are some part of HTML or codes that are related)(also it would be so good if you put a fiddle of your codes)

Comment: So in place of localStorage.key(checked) what i have to replace ?

Comment: its not clear for me do you want to delete data of the selected checkboxes from local storage?

Comment: and there is a delete link that when you click on it, the data of the selected checkboxes from storage right?

Comment: i can make a fiddle but the problem is with the data.. i'm using xml and txt for the data..for making fiddle for this its some what difficult

Comment: ok did you read my updated answer? you should match something and use it to point to data had been stored in localStorage to delete them

Answer (score 1):

`localstorage.removeItem()` wont work as expected. I had faced the same problem while trying to handle the localstorage items.

A work-around for this problem was to **`set the local storage item to null`.** It served my purpose.

For example if you have a localStorage item named `test` then to clear the item use :

```
localStorage.setItem("test", "");
```

Although this may not be the correct way, i had gone bonkers over this issue and the above one served my purpose.

Comment: yes even i'm facing this problem for a long time..not yet solved :(

Comment: @user2384323 : Did u try setting the state to null?

Comment: Hmm, did you ever figure out the underlying problem you were having? I notice IE doesn't work for some user accounts even now, because the browser doesn't have access to its own localStorage files, which seems perversely absurd

Comment: @Ringo : Still searching in the dark.. Have not found a root cause for this particular issue.

Comment: I suspect underdocumented browser issues based on security settings and other preferences.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `localStorage.clear();`